# How to convert u_char* to char[] in C

Tags: c++, c, arrays, char, memcpy

I am working with snmp and the requests->requestvb->val.string function returns me a u_char* and I am trying to store that into a char[255].

```
u_char newValue = *(requests->requestvb->val.string)
char myArray[255];
```

I have tried a few approaches to copy the contents of newValue into myArray but everything seems to segfault. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried
`memcpy(myArray, newValue);`

Another attempt `strncopy(myArray, newValue, sizeof(myArray));`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `newValue` is of type `char`, and for all intents and purposes, your `myArray` is of type `char*`.

First off, I'm going to assume that you're using `memcpy` correctly, and that you're passing in 3 parameters instead of 2, where the 3rd parameter is the same as the one you use in `strncpy`.

When you try using `strncpy` or `memcpy`, you're going beyond the one character "limit" in `newValue` when attempting to copy everything to `myArray`.

The fix should be quite simple:

```
u_char* newValue = requests->requestvb->val.string;
```

Once you've done that, this should work. Of course, that's assuming that the size of `myArray` is in fact greater than or equal to 255 :)

As a side note (and this should go without saying), please make sure that your `myArray` has a null terminating character at the end if you ever plan on printing it. Not having one after performing copy operations, and then trying to print is a very common mistake and can also lead to seg faults.